# call the Web api get method using data params c#

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am able to call the Web api method in client side  and now i want make it in c# code. Here i am writing my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () 
    {
          var Params = 
          {
                    AsOndate: Todate,
                    BCRefCode: 100,
                    AccID: 90000
          };
          $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'http://localhost:51093/api/account/',
                    //url: 'http://192.168.0.171:51093/api/account/',
                    data: Params,
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: ajaxSuccess,
                    error: ajaxError
          });
});
```

and i am calling the web api method

```
public IEnumerable GetAccountListForMapping(Params param)
    {
        AccList _AccList = new AccList();
        ListParams lstParam = new ListParams();
        //lstParam.Add("@FromDate", Fromdate);
        lstParam.Add("@AsOnDate", param.AsOndate);
        lstParam.Add("@BCRefCode", param.BCRefCode);
        lstParam.Add("@AccID", param.AccID);
        _AccList = (AccrList)_AccList.GetAccountMappedList(lstParam);
        return _AccList;
    }
```

This is working good in jquery call.. And how to write the same C# code

This is what i tried

```
        Params param1 = new Params();
        param1.AsOndate = System.DateTime.Today;
        param1.AccID = 90000;
        param1.BCRefCode = 100;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51093/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new  MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/account", param1, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {.....
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method.

```
    string param = "AsOndate=" + System.DateTime.Today + "&AccID=" + 90000 + "&BCRefCode=" + 100;
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/account?" + param,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;
```

Thanks.

Comment: i am getting error: Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(string, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Its Ok Now. Its firing the correct method and returning some 'response'. How can we deserialize this response?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer and it worked for me

```
protected void btnGetdata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxx/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string param = "AsOnDate=" + System.DateTime.Today + "&AccID=" + 90000 + "&BCRefCode=" + 100;
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/account?" + param, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var aa = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>().Result;
            object obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClassName>>(aa.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score -1):

continuing with the answer given by @felix

It will surely get the error as you have not changed the parameter for the api code :

```
    public IEnumerable GetAccountListForMapping(string param)
    {
        // Your Code
    }
```

and now extract that data from the 'param' string.

I hope this will work.